# Apache, putting query string before redirected url?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

is possible to redirect user from url `http://localhost/welcome?url=1&another=2` to index.php?another=2&url=welcome? I mean, I would like to put all query string before the parsed part. Is it possible?

I know I can do something like this:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$     index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&url=$1 [QSD,L]`
and catch URL in php by using `$_SERVER[ 'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' ]` but I wanna get query string from GET array.

If I do just GET I've got url equals to `index.php` (file name), if I change the flag to `QSA`, query string is added after all redirects...

Any ideas?

*-- EDIT --*
I've checked some questions and I found that this is done because of loop.
I've done this, but maybe someone has better idea how to solve this problem.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !&rw=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$           index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&url=$1&rw=1 [QSD,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is possible to redirect user from url `http://localhost/welcome?url=1&another=2` to index.php?another=2&url=welcome?

Yes, you may try this in the .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !index\.php               [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^url=1&([^=]+)=([\d]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)     /index.php?%1=%2&url=$1?          [NC,L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://localhost/par1?url=1&par2=val2`

To:

`http://localhost/index.php?par2=val2&url=par1`

Where *par1*, *par2* and numeric *val2* are dynamic strings.

For permanent redirection, replace [NC,L] with [R=301,NC,L]